# Keep UIButton Size the same when activated multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, constraints

I have a UIButton constraints set to width and height 80 by 80. But when I press the UIbutton to activate a UIScrollView menu, the constraints changes and the button looks like this the image below. (The button is the blue oval shape at the bottom of the screen)

[image]

Here's the viewwcontroller.m codes for the UIbutton and UIscrollview animations.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    draw1 = 1;
}

- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
    if (draw1 ==0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1000, 568, 200);
                             openMenu.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 30, self.view.frame.size.height - 80, 60, 30);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 200);
                             openMenu.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 30, 270, 60, 30);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
    }
}
@end
```

How can you make it so the button constraints says to 80 by 80 and doesn't change when it is activated?

Comment: You don't show any code that manipulates constraints. If your button is changing size as a result of your animation then something strange is going on. It shouldn't change size. Show the constraints on your button.

Comment: Can you make it so the constraints will stay the same anyways?

Comment: They should be staying the same.

Comment: But it doesn't. At first it's 80 by 80 then it gets smaller.

Comment: Show the constraints on your button.

Comment: The constraints are 80 by 80. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ECLPY.png

Answer (score 0):

Please check your selected image. I guess its size is over 80-80. Or maybe, its height > width.